# What is the difference between /it/ and /\Ait\Z/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

In Ruby both expressions seem to do similar things:

```
'it' =~ /^it$/   # 0
'it' =~ /\Ait\Z/ # 0
# but
/^it$/ == /\Ait\Z/ # false
```

So I an wondering what is the difference between `^`-`\A` and `$`-`\Z` and how to choose which one to use?

Comment: Isn't there a typo in your example? Should be `/\Ait\Z/`, right?

Comment: @All: Wondering which answer I should accept as all of them are very clear? I'll do it by the number of Up-Votes in a couple of days probably.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference is only important when the string you are matching against can contain new lines. `\A` matches the start of a string. `^` matches either the start of a string or immediately after a new line. Similarly `\Z` only matches the end of the string, but `$` matches the end of the string or the end of a line.

For example, the regular expression [`/^world$/`](http://rubular.com/r/rCRi1aLZ9N) matches the second line of "hello\nworld" but the expression [`/\Aworld\Z/`](http://rubular.com/r/b2sF7wY85W) fails to match.

Answer (score 5):

In regex engines that support multi-line regular expressions, `^` and `$` are usually used for start and end of *line* markers.

`\A` and `\Z` are for start and end of *string* markers.

For example, the string:

```
Hello, my names
are Bob and James
```

would match `ames$` twice (for names and James) but `ames\Z` only once (for James).

Answer (score 2):

`^` - start of line
`\A` - start of string

`$` - end of line
`\Z` - end of string